# Joining 2 lists ,Python

Tags: python, list

How do I join 2 lists with elements side by side? For example:

```
list1 = ["they" , "are" ,"really" , "angry"]  
list2 = ["they" , "are" ,"seriously" , "angry"]
```

I want output as:

```
list3 = [("they","they"),("are","are"),("really","seriously"),("angry","angry")]
```

The above looks like a list tuples though, and if the above list were columns with each word in a row, how would I append list2 to list1?

Comment: Using [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip).

Comment: this type of question has plenty in SO, please check.

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning that if the lists are of uneven length, `zip` will discard the remaining elements of the longer list. You can use [itertools.izip_longest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) if this is the case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> list1 = ["they" , "are" ,"really" , "angry"]  
>>> list2 = ["they" , "are" ,"seriously" , "angry"] 
>>> list3 = zip(list1, list2)
>>> list3
[('they', 'they'), ('are', 'are'), ('really', 'seriously'), ('angry', 'angry')]
```

Comment: what if i have 2 columns instead??

Answer (score 3):

This is another solution,

```
>>> [ (val,list2[idx]) for idx, val in enumerate(list1)]
[('they', 'they'), ('are', 'are'), ('really', 'seriously'), ('angry', 'angry')]
```

By the way zip() is a good solution.